# Lowest IPv6 host address in an address range

Tags: ipv6

What is the lowest IPv6 host address in an address range; is it A:B:C:D:E:F:0:0/64 or A:B:C:D:E:F:0:1/64? Does IPv6 have a network address (0 = "this") like IPv4? I know one address type is depricated in IPv6, but I can't remember which one.

My copy of Douglas E. Comers' "Internetworking with TCP/IP Vol.1: Principles, Protocols, and Architecture (4th Edition)" is a few hundred kilometres away, so I can't check.

- A, B, C, D, E, and F do not denote hexadecimal numbers, but rather unknown numbers.

Comment: I suppoe I can use A:B:C:D:E:F:0:0 if the subnet is trully /64, because all 2^16 IPv6 IPs I've been assigned are, basically, host addresses. Opinions?

Comment: On a side note, after deciding to use A:B:C:D:E:F:0:0 as the IPv6 address using your opinions, I am now waiting for my DNS provider to solve their DNS returning random AAAA records for my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XYZ::0 address (where the host part of the address is set to all 0s) is the [subnet-router anycast address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.6.1).

See [Linux IPv6 loopback routes getting automatically added](https://serverfault.com/questions/200344/linux-ipv6-loopback-routes-getting-automatically-added) where I discovered that although you can use a ::0 address on some equipment (e.g. Cisco), it breaks other equipment (like Linux).

Comment: Both work for me, but I was unsure whether it was the result of anycast or unicast. Is A:B:C:D:E:F:0:0/64 an anycast or a unicast address?

Comment: F is not 0. [text to fullfill the minimal comment length requirement]

Comment: That is a unicast address (all else being equal, i.e. the block not being an anycast/multicast block).

Comment: Wow, you learn something new everyday, indeed the ::0 address is responded to by the (linux) router. I've seen ::0 addresses in use as destination, such as http://[2600::]/ for a sprint webserver which still works. www.sprint.com points to 2600::aaaa.

Answer (score 0):

It might be important to note that while Zanchey's answer is correct with regards to x::0 hosts, the example in the question does not describe a ::0 host.

The example was A:B:C:D:E:F:0:0/64.  A:B:C:D is the network portion, and the host address is actually E:F:0:0, not 0.